# Bipartite graph maximum matching

Tags: graph-algorithm, bipartite

I am new to graphs. I have two sets in a bipartite graph. I need to find unique matching of all the possible combinations. So I thought I use Hopcroft-Karp to find maximum matching. Being a newbie I thought I would get the resulting matching graph but all it tells me is 42. Ahhh that really helps. I don't need to know how many matchings there are I need to know the unique matchings themselfs.

Am I missing something? How do I get the resulting matching?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly is to be done and what is "42"?

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275462/how-to-solve-this-variation-of-kirkkmans-schoolgirls)

Comment: Ops, should have checked all class variables. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I diden't check the datastructures generated by the Hopcroft-Karp match function, only the retrun value. The return value is the number of matchings. However there was also a self.pair dictionary in the python code, the pair dictionary contains the matchings from "both" sides, which answers my question.